# Offset pandas date column using a varying time period

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where there is a date column (year- month-day) and a frequency column. I want to create a new column by offsetting the date column by the weeks in the frequency column.

For example:

```
 date        |freq  |offset date 
 2019-01-01  |4     |2019-01-29
 2019-03-01  |8     |2019-04-26
```

I am trying to use this code:

```
df['offset date'] = df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(weeks=df["freq"])
df.head()
```

However it is not letting me pass the `freq` column as an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try offset with `timedelta`:

```
df['offset date'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['freq'], unit='W')
```